# Sql conditional statement on where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to make a query using a conditional to select a clause for filter.
Something like this.

```
SELECT Id,name,last_name,submitDate,lastvisitDate 
from Visitor Where if(submitDate is not null) begin submitDate >= @dateFrom end
and if(submitDate is not null) begin submitDate < @dateTo end
```

but I need for example if `@dateTo is null` this variable doesn't participate on the filter query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `ISNULL` to `@dateTo` and thus default it to some really distant future date, like `30000101`:

```
…
WHERE submitDate IS NULL
   OR submitDate >= @dateFrom AND submitDate < ISNULL(@dateTo, '30000101')
```

Comment: but when you say is null, the select will look for null values on that field?

Comment: @JuanCarlosVegaNeira: No, [`ISNULL()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx "ISNULL (Transact-SQL)") merely returns the second argument if the first one is NULL, otherwise it returns the first argument. In my example, ISNULL effectively provides a default value for `@dateTo` in case it is NULL. So, if `@dateTo` *is* NULL, `submitDate` will be compared to a very big value, which would be the same as if we just ignored that condition, because it would certainly return `true`.

Answer (score 2):

```
where (submitDate is null or (submitDate >= @dateFrom and submitDate < @dateTo))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Visitor where (submitDate is null or submitDate >= @dateFrom) and (submitDate is null or submitDate < @dateTo)
```

Comment: `(A or B) and (A or C) = A or (B and C)`. Therefore, your suggestion is equivalent to `submitDate is null or (submitDate >= @dateFrom and submitDate < @dateTo)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the WHERE clause of your example query, so that records will be included in the results if submitDate is null or if submitDate is between @dateFrom and @dateTo

```
SELECT Id, name, last_name, submitDate, lastvisitDate 
FROM Visitor 
WHERE (submitDate IS NULL) OR ((submitDate >= @dateFrom) AND (submitDate < @dateTo))
```